# Determine if a generic type is a primitive or enum with underlying primitive at compile time C++ in a function

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming

I'm trying to determine at compile time within a template function if the type T is either a primitive type or an enum with underlying primitive type.

In code, I'm trying to do this

```
template <typename T>
bool foo(T& input)
{    
    bool isPrimitive = std::is_fundamental<T>::value || (std::is_enum<T>::value && std::is_fundamental<std::underlying_type<T>::type>::value);
    // We want to do things using isPrimitive, but not important so omitted.
    return isPrimitive; //return this value just to avoid warnings.
}
```

This fails to compile when foo is invoked with T not being an enum, since `std::underlying_type<T>::type` doesn't exist in that case.

```
enum class Bar : int
{
    DUMMYCASE,
};

int main()
{
    int test1;
    Bar test2;
    foo(test1); // fails
    foo(test2); // ok
}
```

I've looked at std::conditional and std::enable_if, as well as this answer [SFINAE not happening with std::underlying_type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36568050/sfinae-not-happening-with-stdunderlying-type/36568565#36568565) but cannot see how this can be done.  It seems like enable_if only works in template params.

How can I rewrite the line such that it compiles when T is not an enum?  Ideally I would like to avoid changing the function signature.

`bool isPrimitive = std::is_fundamental<T>::value || (std::is_enum<T>::value && std::is_fundamental<std::underlying_type<T>::type>::value);`

Comment: Under what circumstances is the underlying type of an enum *not* a fundamental type? It has to be an integral type, right? And all integral types are fundamental.

Comment: The underlying type is always integral.

Comment: Thanks to you both.  I can remove the redundant check then which solves the problem.  For learning purposes, if we take another example where we wanted to accomplish the same thing but it wasn't redundant, is it possible?

Comment: It would be quite easy with C++17 `if constexpr`, otherwise you'd have to go for some actual metaprogramming (still possible, just a lot of boilerplate code and less easy to udnerstand).

Comment: And in C++20 you could use a concept: `template <typename T> concept isPrimitive = std::is_fundamental<T>::value || /*and so on*/;`. In those, a SFINAE failure automatically returns false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Beside the fact that enums support only integral types you could write:

```
template <typename T>
bool foo(T& input)
{
    constexpr bool isPrimitive = [](){
        if constexpr (std::is_fundamental_v<T>){
            return true;
        }
        if constexpr (std::is_enum_v<T>){
            using underlying_type = typename std::underlying_type<T>::type;
            if constexpr (std::is_fundamental_v<underlying_type>){
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }();

    // We want to do things using isPrimitive, but not important so omitted.
    return isPrimitive; //return this value just to avoid warnings.
}
```

The problem with your code is, that std::underlying_type is instantiated for non-enums, too.
In addition there is a missing typename disambiguator.

`std::underlying_type<T>::type` is a dependent name and must be prefixed with "typename" - otherwise the compiler asumes a non-type.